# CDF Enterprise : Protection and licensing

Tags: cdf-format

I am new to Mathematica but on top of that I am asked to create a CDF file that is IP protected (encrypted) and also licensed.

In [this video](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?c=89&v=596)
they are giving the way to protect the code. At the end the presenter mentions a license option, but they don't provide any information how to do this.

Is there any way that I can create an external installation file, and wrap the CDF file with Java or HTML so that I can create a license check?

Comment: This may be more of a question for WRI support or http://community.wolfram.com.